# drupal smtp module no reply-to option

Tags: email, drupal, smtp, drupal-modules

On drupal 6 i have the smtp module installed and i can't figure out how to change the reply-to address.

In the "smtp.module" file I have added the lines:

```
$form['email_options']['smtp_replyto'] = array(
'#type'          => 'textfield',
'#title'         => t('Reply-to Email address'),
'#default_value' => variable_get('smtp_replyto', ''),
'#description'   => t('The reply-to E-mail address'),);
```

right after the line 181 where is the `$form['email_options']['smtp_fromname']` decleration.

So this field shows up correctly in the administrative panel in the  'SMTP authentication support'. I can't figure out how to make the system take this address and replace it in the reply-to field of the email instead of the sender's mail.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_mail_alter: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6 to change it before the mail was sended.

Comment: yes it seems that this going to help. but how do i use this code. i can't find my core.php file in my drupal 6 site? do i add this code in the smtp.module file?

Comment: No, you need to write a custom module and code a function named [MY_MODULE]_mail_ater(&$message). More info: http://drupal.org/developing/modules

Comment: I am a bit confused. I have the module smtp. Don't I have to make the changes there? I can't find the hooks in there.

Comment: I think you need to read how the hook mechanism works in Drupal :-)

Comment: yes you are right. But I am reading it the last hour and i was wondering if I could implement the xxx_mail_alter() hook inside inside the smtp.module . What if I replace the smtp_mail hook? or add it after that?

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the drupal core code or the code of contributed modules (or themes). Your code for logic or personalizations must reside in custom modules (or custom themes), this way you can update your drupal core and contributes modules with no fear of losing your code. More info: http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core